# Deserialize and reserialize SOobject

Tags: apex, json, deserialize, serialize

i have an object like this:

```
evticket__c et = [Select Id from evticket__c where Id =: id limit 1];
```

then i serialize it likethis:

```
String obj = JSON.serialize(et);
```

is there a way to create a new object with that serialized data something like this:

```
evticket__c newEt = JSON.deserialize(obj );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work - you need to cast it back to the Concrete object, and specify the type you want the JSON parser to use:

```
Account a = [Select Id, Name, Type from Account LIMIT 1];
String sJSON = JSON.serialize(a);

Account js = (Account)json.deserialize(sjson, account.class);
system.debug(js);
```